# SQL Query: To display only one email address

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I have a query which I would like to display is only one email address.

Description:

Below are three 3 different query. First query gives location, second query gives department and last query is for customer who are attending an event between specific date. After having this query, I am displaying emailaddress with row number and email exist from specific part.

```
with temp as  (
    Select Distinct 'A' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        and State IN ('NY','FL','CA','IL','GA') 
        and City IN ('Albany','Long Beach','Middletown','New York','Miami','Orlando','Tempa','Jacksoneville','Los Angeles','San Diego','Chicago','Aurora','Rockford','Atlanta','Savannah','Athens')
        Union

    Select Distinct 'B' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        AND deptno IN ('5','9','8','7')

    UNION

    Select Distinct 'C' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        AND AttDate between 2015/01/08 and 2015/01/25


) select *, Row_number() over ( partition BY email ORDER BY email) rn from temp
```

Output

```
Part    ID          Email               rn
A       21345       jjohnson@abc.com    1
A       73245       tferna@abc.com      1
B       21356       tferna@abc.com      2
A       13343       scardon@abc.com     2
C       14564       bmethews@abc.com    3   
A       54656       pwilliams@abc.com   5
B       34156       pwilliams@abc.com   2
C       12368       pwilliams@abc.com   3
A       54631       kpearce@abc.com     2   
A       87966       mjordan@abc.com     1
```

Now, I would like to display only one email address which from every part. In my output table there are two email address which are in different part (section).

So, how can I display only one email address even though it exist in another part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your result query as another CTE and change code to the following

```
select *, Row_number() over ( partition BY Part ORDER BY Part) rn from temp
```

After that you can write select * from cte WHERE rn=1

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question

```
`with temp as  (
    Select Distinct 'A' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        and State IN ('NY','FL','CA','IL','GA') 
        and City IN ('Albany','Long Beach','Middletown','New York','Miami','Orlando','Tempa','Jacksoneville','Los Angeles','San Diego','Chicago','Aurora','Rockford','Atlanta','Savannah','Athens')
        Union

    Select Distinct 'B' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        AND deptno IN ('5','9','8','7')

    UNION

    Select Distinct 'C' AS Part, ID, Email Address 
    from c_detail
        where a.status = 1
        AND AttDate between 2015/01/08 and 2015/01/25


), temp_result AS ( select *, Row_number() over ( partition BY email ORDER BY email) rn from temp)
select * from temp_result WHERE rt.rn=1`
```

Thank You @AdrianChodkowski